# Implement a custom Y axis in chart.js using an array of values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was unable to find the answer to this question. I'm a relative beginner in Javascript and chart.js, and I'm having a problem with customizing a line graph. I want to graph the difficulty of rock climbs, which use something called the Yosemite Decimal System. Is there a way to provide an array of values for the Y axis? Here is a short example of an array of climbing route values:

["5.10a", "5.10b", "5.10c", "5.10d", "5.11a", "5.11b", "5.11c", "5.11d", "5.12a"]

Is there a simple way to provide something like this as a scale for the Y axis? Or is it more complicated, necessitating the use of a comparator function or something like that?

Thanks!